# I have an arraylist of different objects: how do I use a lambda to pull out a list of certain types?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, arraylist

For simplicity, say I have an ArrayList that contains objects of type A, B & C. How do I pull out just objects of type A?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No need to even write a lambda expression. The built-in [`OfType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) method is exactly what you need:

```
var onlyTypeA = yourArrayList.OfType<A>();
```

Comment: Interesting.  Didn't know `OfType` operates on non-generic `IEnumerable`.